# Trouble Combining Raw Socket with Hugepages

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, mmap, raw-sockets

I want to have a hugepage (2MByte) ring buffer with my raw UDP socket reader in linux (ubuntu 18.04).  I can create the raw socket:

socket_fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0);

I could create a normal memory (4KB pages) ring buffer with mmap:

```
    void * rxring_buffer = mmap(nullptr, size_in_bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, socket_fd, 0);
```

However, I don't see an obvious path to using a hugepage ring buffer.  My initial try was to use MAP_HUGETLB with mmap.  However as can be seen from https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/testing/selftests/vm/map_hugetlb.c , that option seems to only work with MAP_ANONYMOUS which does not allow a file (or socket) backing.

I can create the huge shared memory buffer with:

```
    int mem_fd = open("/mnt/huge/hugepagefs", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0755);
    void * big_buff_ptr = mmap(nullptr, size_in_bytes,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, 0));
```

but I don't see a path to assign it to the socket ring buffer.

Is there a way to assign the hugepage shared memory to a ring buffer?